# Show that the image of a linear transformation $T$ from $\mathbb{R^{n\times m}}$ to $F(\mathbb{R^m},\mathbb{R^n})$ is...

Tags: linear-algebra

For a matrix $A$ in $\mathbb{R^{n\times m}}$, the value $T(A)$ will be a function from $\mathbb{R^m}$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$, and $(T(A))(\vec{v}) = A\vec{v}$.

1. Show that the image of $T$ is the space $L(\mathbb{R^m}, \mathbb{R^n})$ of all linear transformation from $\mathbb{R^m}$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$.
2. Find $dim(L(\mathbb{R^m}, \mathbb{R^n}))$.

For 1: I know that the image of $T$ is defined as the set of all $A\vec{v}$ for some $A\in \mathbb{R^{n\times m}}$ and $\vec{v}\in \mathbb{R^m}$, but how is this equal to the space of all linear transformation from $\mathbb{R^m}$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$? It seems like it's just equal to $\mathbb{R^n}$.

I suppose 2 will follow from a solution to 1, so I'll hold on asking questions about the dimension.

Comment: The image of $T$ is set of all $T(A)$!

Comment: Now, the image is the set of all linear transformations $T$ such that $T(A)(\vec{v})=A\vec{v}$.  First show that the kernel is null so that the image is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.  Then show that it is a surjection (hint: you can determine a matrix by its actions on the standard basis elements).  This shows that the dimension of $L(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$ is equal to that of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.

Answer (score 0):

For 1: The image of $T$ is *not* the set of all $A\vec{v}$! I'm not sure if the question you were given was phrased poorly or not, but $T$ is really a map
$$
T : \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \to Hom_{Sets}(\mathbb{R}^m, \mathbb{R}^n)
$$
given by $T(A) = \{\vec{v} \mapsto A\vec{v}\}$.

The point is that to a matrix we can associate a function from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by the formula above. In particular, this function is linear (which you can and probably have already shown), and so it lands in the subset of the *linear* maps, which is often just denoted $Hom(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$. The map $T$ then gives this association.

Remember that, strictly speaking, a matrix is just a box of numbers! To make it a linear transformation we need to describe how it acts on vectors; that is what the function $T$ does.

Comment: So how would you define the image of $T$? If it's not $A\vec{v}$, then what is it?

Comment: If we fix some $A_{n\times m}$, then for all $\vec{v}\in \mathbb{R^m}$, we have a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R^m}$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$. And we can keep fixing different $A$'s. Isn't this the desired image we want?

Comment: This is one of those things that is simpler than you think it is, and consequently is a little confusing. Remember that $A\vec{v}$ is just a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so it's not a function at all.

Comment: By contrast, $T(A)$ is the function that takes as input the vector $\vec{v}$, and gives you the vector $A\vec{v}$.

Comment: So the image of $T(A)$ acting on $\vec{v}$ is just $A\vec{v}$, as you said. But the image of $T$, acting on $A$ is a function, not a vector.

Comment: So $T$ can act on any matrix $A$, right? And for some matrix it acts on the function outputs $A\vec{v}$ for every $\vec{v}\in \mathbb{R^m}$? So this is the same as every linear transformation from $\mathbb{R^m}$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Comment: While that is true, you would have to show that every linear transformation can be written as a matrix. If you know that fact, then you're gold.

Answer (score 0):

The $\implies$ is totally trivial: check that $\vec{v}\mapsto A\vec{v}$ is linear. The interesting implication is the other, i.e., any element of $L(\mathbb{R^m}, \mathbb{R^n})$ is $\vec{v}\mapsto A\vec{v}$ for some $A$. Hint: take the canonical basis in both sides ($\mathbb{R^m}$ and $\mathbb{R^n}$). Also important/interesting: prove that $T$ is linear.